# Active background not working in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that highlights the way I want (white) when I hover over the selection. If the user activates the highlighted page, I want to change the background of the word to stay white until another page is selected (the way I show below). But, it only stays white when hovered, not when active.

Here's my shared CSS that works for the hover but not for the active page:

```
 .topmenu a:hover {
    color:#000;
    background-color: #fff;
 }

 .topmenu a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #f00;
 }
```

`
Here's my navigation bar:

```
<div class="topmenu">
    <li><a href="home.html">RICHARD COUTTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="architecture.html">architecture</a></li>
    <li><a href="ee.html">engineering</a></li>
    <li><a href="software.html">software</a></li>
    <li><a href="theory.html">theory</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code and did some change in active and hover class. You did not write ul element which is parent of li element. so i added ul and  changed your ul elements's background color so when mouse hover, white background color can display.

Css:

```
 
       ul      
        {    
            background-color: olive;
        }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            color: #000;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        .active {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #f00;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="topmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="home.html">RICHARD COUTTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="architecture.html">architecture</a></li>
            <li><a href="ee.html">engineering</a></li>
            <li><a href="software.html">software</a></li>
            <li><a href="theory.html">theory</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```